# How to change default video player app inside Hangouts

Tags: default-applications, google-hangouts

A video appeared inside a Hangouts chat stream and when I clicked it, it asked me which installed app I intend to use for playing that video.

I accidentally picked some casting app, but apparently (and surprisingly) the *Use as default app* was also checked, so whenever I click a video inside a Hangouts chat stream it tries to cast to a non-existing device and fails.

The system-wide video app is set to a normal video player app, but I can't find out how to set the default app for playing videos *inside* Hangouts.

Any idea how to reset it without uninstalling either app?

Comment: Us this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aboutmycode.betteropenwith&hl=en_IN) to reset and define the selected app for hangouts again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far it is not Hangouts that need to be cleared in this case but the app which got registered as a default player.

Goto Settings -> Apps -> [Select the App that open when you play video inside Hangouts] -> Click Set as Default -> CLEAR DEFAULTS